# Given the center position, rotation angle, elongation and scaling parameters of the ellipse, draw the ellipse

Tags: matlab-figure

I want to draw the effect picture in this paper《Kernel Regression for Image Processing
and Reconstruction》.As shown below，Given the center position, rotation angle, elongation and scaling parameters of the ellipse, draw the ellipse[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgfve.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2S7OX.png)

I don't know how to draw the effect of false color in the second picture

Answer (score 0):

Actually I know how to draw what you are talking about, however now I think this drawing method is not used in the thesis. You can calculate the rotation, stretching, and scaling according to the formula in the paper based on the gradient matrix calculation, and then draw an ordinary circle to draw a heat map.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34455245)